# Would a question about a type of video games be acceptable?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm looking to post a question regarding open world games, and their relative size.

Would a question like this be too broad if I narrowed it down to terminating worlds?

The specific question is "What non-procedurally generated game has the largest filled and terminating open world space to date and how large is it (in relative terms)?".

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: If I asked this question, would it be on topic, and not get closed? I don't want to post a low quality question for the site.

Comment: No, no, I meant could you say what the question you're trying to ask is? My thinking is it would be too broad, but it might also be off-topic, but it depends on the question.

Comment: Ah I'll add in an edit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Now that you've posted your question, the issue isn't with broadness.

The problem with this question is that it actually boils down to being a question about game identification, which is off-topic without an artifact.

From the Closure reason:

> Questions asking for help identifying a game, whether based on a description, or feature list, **or any other set of criteria** are off-topic; this blog post might help. We allow an exception for identifying games based on an actual piece of the game, such as screenshots or audio clips.

I've bolded the part of the closure reason that your question would fall under.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Yet another question I wish we could answer that this annoying rule prevents us from answering. Wish this wasn't the community consensus, but it appears to be.

Comment: @DCShannon Game recommendations are off-topic for extremely good reasons.  It's not annoying, it's specifically self-preserving.  These make for yes, popular, and ultimately completely problematic questions.

Comment: @Frank I don't want to delve into another argument with you, Frank. All I'll say, is that game recommendations aren't significantly different than book or movie recommendations, which are handled just fine on the Sci-Fi and Movies exchanges.

Comment: I'm confused. I said this type of question is off topic for identification, not recommendation... but either way, identification and recommendations are handled on a site-by-site basis, so comparing Arqade to other SE sites isn't really a good argument for validity.

Comment: @Vemonus is your name misspelled? (i mean Venomous feels correct)

Comment: @Fennekin yes, it's a bastardization of "Venomous". But that's the point-- it's my favorite MapleStory character's name, which came from the fact that Venomous wasn't available.